# System events with vb.net service

Tags: vb.net, service, systemevent

I try to create windows service to write events win windows sessionswitch event, but when I make it in windows application it work fine but doesn't work with service.
After search I know the system events need message loop enabled so how I can enable it in vb.net windows service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to receive Windows Messages, your program must have a window. As noted on the [SessionSwitch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.systemevents.sessionswitch(v=vs.110).aspx) MSDN page:

> In a Windows service, unless a hidden form is used or the message pump
>   has been started manually, this event will not be raised.

A link is included which gives an example showing how to receive these events with a hidden window. [Message Only Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632599(v=vs.85).aspx#message_only) are another, similar option for receiving window events and messages.